# Enable Core Dump for already running processes in Redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, coredump

I understand that I can enable Core Dumps for new processes by making below entry in /etc/profile file
`ulimit -c unlimited >/dev/null 2>&1`

Is it anyhow possible to enable core dumps for already running processes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/201207/set-max-file-limit-on-a-running-process) says,

(On CentOs/Red Hat) If you have a kernel 2.6.32+, you can change it manually as below:

```
cd /proc/7671/
[root@host 7671]# cat limits  | grep nice
Max nice priority         0                    0
[root@host 7671]# echo -n "Max nice priority=5:6" > limits
[root@host 7671]# cat limits  | grep nice
Max nice priority         5                    6
```

Otherwise, you can use the `prlimit` tool (introduced with util-linux 2.21), as follows:

```
[root@host 986]# prlimit --core=1000000 --pid 23578
[root@host 986]# prlimit --pid 23578 | grep CORE
CORE       max core file size                   1000000   1000000 bytes
```

Hope it helps